# is it a good idea to use gitlab config trigger API call toward some service?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I know it might not be the best case, but due to some limitations, I have to do, THe API call will need to be triggered through GitLab.
The service is running in a place that only gitlab is able to access.
My expectation is the query toward the service , query per min < 100.  however, as long as it can be pushed out whenever it needs to be done, it will be good.

Gitlab will be pushed out to the service, and GitLab hold the config which can do that.

Is this a good idea? or are any other constrain you can suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. Are there specific concerns you have? As written, it's not clear to me that there is a specific question here. In general, it's best if questions are not written to be opinion-based. Could you perhaps rephrase the question in a way that would not get opinion-based answers?

Comment: my concern is it a good experience to trigger API call like this? push base by config does require MR and that sometimes is slow if I want male a stop signal through this. Either start and stop signal made through Gitlab will need to be merged